# TYPO3 12: Link to page inside folder doesn't work

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I'm working on a metanavigation that should link to a number of pages inside a folder. Currently my page tree looks something like this:

- Home
- Meta Navigation (Folder)

  - Search
  - Login

However, when trying to link to one of the pages inside the folder using following code;

`<f:link.page pageUid="{item.data.uid}">{item.data.title}</f:link.page>`

the link isn't generated.

I've tried replacing `{"item.data.uid}"` with the page id, which also didn't render any link in the frontend. However, when I replaced the variable with the page id of "Home", which isn't inside a folder, the link got rendered in the frontend.

I'm guessing that I'm missing some typoscript config, that allows me to link to pages inside of folders, but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Is this your full page tree? Or is there any parent page?

There should be one main page ("Home") and all pages that belong to the same "site" should be inside that. Every "root" page have an own site configuration which is required for url resolving.

Comment: You're right, I completely missed that. Moved the rest of the pages inside my main page and now it works. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jan already correctly mentioned in the comments you need to place the folder with your meta navigation pages inside your root-page.

- Home

  - Meta Navigation (Folder)

    - Search
    - Login

Else the routing to your pages won't work.